# Ping сервера по протоколу HTTP

Tags: веб-программирование, http

**Доброго времени суток!**

В данный момент создаю приложение, которое работает с сетью( взаимодействует с веб сервером по протоколу HTTP ). В первой версии допустил **фатальную ошибку**( что ж, ошибки свойственны людям ), которая приводила к пингу сервера каждые 0.1 секунды на **несуществующий адрес**! При чем, это происходило, как минимум, с 10 клиентских ПК. А это уже мини DDoS. Итог: доступ к хостингу и все, что на нем располагалось, заблокировали на 24 часа. Пришлось повозиться, чтобы отыскать ошибку. Ошибка исправлена. Допустим, теперь одназначно не будет пинговаться несуществующий адрес, но как тогда быть с интервалом пинга? Мне почему-то первое, что пришло на ум, это 1 секунда. Т.е пинг с частотой в одну секунду. Не возникнет ли при этом дикой нагрузки на сервер, расцененной хостерами, как DDoS( или даже DoS )? Какое время в данном случае было бы оптимально, скажем, если пользователей приложением будет не более 100, к примеру ?

**Большое спасибо!**

Comment: Почему-то мне кажется, что Вы постоянно обращались к скрипту PHP, поэтому машина падала при сравнительно небольшом количестве запросов. Пингуйте запрашивая статику, например создайте пустой файл **ping.pong** в .htaccess напишите:  

    AddType ping/pong .pong
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType ping/pong "now"
Так будет быстрее, чем дергать php.

Comment: @ReinRaus, спасибо. Но, во-первых, вдруг на хостинге у Apache отключен модуль mod_expires ? Во-вторых, пинг( обращение ) и правда происходит к PHP скрипту. Это не случайно. Хранить что-либо в кэше нет смылса, так как клиенты обращаются к скрипту для получения информации, которая меняется очень часто( до нескольких раз в минуту ). Вот так.

Comment: Если информация одинакова для всех клиентов, то можно одним постоянно работающим PHP скриптом генерировать файл с актуальными данными, а клиенты будут обращаться к результату как к статике. Лучше конечно отдельного демона написать, который будет с клиентами через сокеты общаться, но я так понимаю хостинг этого не позволяет.

Comment: В общем, какой бы интервал не был установлен, сервер рано или поздно упадет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объясните, какой смысл насиловать сервер каждую секунду. Если вам нужно оповещать клиента об изменениях в системе, то для этих целей есть long-pool запросы.

Да, на стандартном хостинге вы раньше или позже упретесь в планку одновременного количества соединений с сайтом... Но если делать как вы, даже с интервалом в 1 секунду - то вас когда-то прикроют за дикую нагрузку на сервер.

Вариантов у вас есть три:

- искать хостинг с разрешенными long-запросами, но я таких не встречал;
- держать сайт на дешевом хостинге, и уменьшить интервал опроса, скажет до 15-30 секунд. Есть целая куча задач, где 30 секунд погоды не делают;
- смотреть в сторону VDS. Если вам реально нужно качество. Это всего лишь 12-15$ в месяц - для живого проекта - не сумма;

Comment: Что ж, все хуже, чем я предполагал...

Comment: Тяжело только в первый раз. Дальше уютно и приятно)